# como creo una base de datos con netbeans y msql en mi documento de itextpdf

Tags: java, msql, itextpdf

Hola quiero comentarles que estoy haciendo un proyecto en netbeans con msql y itextpdf no me creaba el documento ya lo pude crear pero no salio con la lista de datos pienso que algo le falta a mi código para que pueda crear el documento con la lista de datos que ordenes tengo que darle a netbeans para que el documento tenga su lista de datos[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIaON.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKh4P.png este es el documento pero debe llevar la siguiente lista [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] y el documento me crea los títulos de las celdas pero no crea la lista en cada una de la celdas yo pienso que me falta algún elemento mas a escribir en netbeans para que msql y itexpdf puedan crear el documento que puedo hacer para que el documento tenga los datos aparte de los titulos

esa es la imagen del codigo de netbeans y la del documento incompleto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] necesito que el documento tenga la lista de datos mi codigo en netbeans es el siguiente

Document documento = new Document(PageSize.A4,50,50,50,50);

```
    try {
        String ruta = System.getProperty("user.Onedrive");
       try {
           PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, (new FileOutputStream( "C:/temp/Reporte_Alumnos.pdf")));
       } catch (DocumentException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(RegistroAlumnos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
        documento.open();
        
        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(3);
        tabla.addCell("Còdigo");
        tabla.addCell("Nombre del Alumno");
        tabla.addCell("Grupo");
        
        try {
            Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:msql://localhost/bd_ins","root", "");
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("select * from alumnos");
            
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            
            if(rs.next()){
                
                do {
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(1));
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(2));
                    tabla.addCell(rs.getString(3));
                } while (rs.next());
                documento.add(tabla);
            }
                
        } catch (DocumentException | SQLException e) {
        }
        documento.add(tabla);
         
         documento.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reporte creado.");
    } catch (HeadlessException e) {    
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistroAlumnos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistroAlumnos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }    
    
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegistroAlumnos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegistroAlumnos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegistroAlumnos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegistroAlumnos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RegistroAlumnos().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel label_status;
private javax.swing.JTextField txt_buscar;
private javax.swing.JTextField txt_grupo;
private javax.swing.JTextField txt_nombre;
// End of variables declaration
```

es el mismo de la imagen de netbeans que les mande pero pienso ah de estar incompleto porque me crea el documento pero la base de datos no diganme que codigo de mas debo añadir al jframe de netbeans para crear el documento completo

Comment: Buenas, Schager, las dos imágenes son iguales, ¿no? Los datos que tienes en tu base de datos puedes incluirlos como texto en lugar de esas capturas de tu gestor de base de datos. Por otro lado, deberías incluir el código java con el que consultas la base de datos y generas el documento para que se te pueda ayudar.

Comment: `} catch (DocumentException | SQLException e) {}` Si tienes cualquier error en la consulta de SQL o al generar el PDF lo ignoras. Así es muy difícil averiguar que te pasa; es como si fueras al médico y no le dijeras qué te pasa y te negaras a que te hicieran pruebas, y esperaras que el médico entienda qué te pasa. Como mínimo imprime en algún sitio el stacktrace de la excepción (si es que se captura).

Comment: gracias por el consejo así lo haré.

Comment: miren no puedo imprimirlo pero si puedo mandarles las tomas del código y ustedes me están diciendo que les de lo mas importante lo que demuestra el error lo voy a hacer